# Self Organizing Lists - Movo-to-Front List Rearrangement

Tags: list, linked-list

I have this exercise:

> Construct a pair of list orders that differ by exactly n(n - 1)/2 inversions.

And I tried to solve it:

"A -> B -> C -> D -> E
B -> A -> C -> D -> E

A -> B -> C -> D -> E
E -> A -> B -> C -> D   (2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 4)"

Really, for n=5, we have 5(5-1)/2=10.

However, I got doubts:

1. I'm not certain if initial lists pairs or arrangements must be different.
2. I should make more rearrangements.

Comment: I'm really not clear what the question is here...

Comment: First, I don't know if the nunber of inversions is correct on 2nd list order.
And if the pair of list orders is based on same initial list, @PhatWrat.